# tokenizing a dataframe using unnest_tokens gives me error?

Tags: r, nlp, tokenize

I am new to R and been trying to tokenize a data.frame using unnest_tokens. My data.frame was obtained from a csv file and has the following column :

> ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, OUTCOMES, DATE .

I WISH TO TOKENIZE THE TITLE, SO I MADE ANOTHER DATAFRAME :

```
only_t<-dplyr::select(mydata,title)
up_dat<-data.frame(1:2156, document= only_t)
```

Followed by I did :

```
up_dat %>%
  tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, document)
```

When I did this , I get an error stating :

> Error in check_input(x) :    Input must be a character vector of any
>   length or a list of character   vectors, each of which has a length of
>   1.

Would appreciate any help in this. I been stuck here forever .

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Check this out : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465241/error-in-check-inputx-input-must-be-a-character-vector-of-any-length-or-a-li

Comment: hey @ShubhamPujan I looked into it and I have the issue with my tibble . # A tibble: 2,156 x 2
   X1.2156 title                                                                                     
     <int> <fct>  . Considering i need to convert it into a character using mutate.